# How to display those errors which are disabled by @-operator - Error Control Operators?

Tags: php, error-handling, php-7

I am using some external libraries which uses the `@` error silencing operator.

The library is generating some errors and it becomes difficult to point the exact location where the error occurs as the `@` operator hides it.

Is there any way to easily disable the @-operator in the code without making any actual changes to the code?

I have tried Scream Pecl extension but it does not seem to work. It's available for PHP 5.6 version while I am using PHP 7.

Scream extension is installed and is enabled in php.ini by using `scream.enabled=1` (as per their documentation) but the error still doesn't show or log.

Comment: which external library uses @ operator? maybe there is some way to use some other symbol instead of @.

Comment: @Athul Fusionbb (http://www.fusionbb.com Although it's no longer maintained ) uses the @-operator for ignoring the errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot disable the behaviour of the `@` symbol, but you can log/handle these errors nonetheless by using your own error handler.

From the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php):

> If you have set a custom error handler function with `set_error_handler()` then it will still get called,

What this operator does is basically set `error_reporting` to `0` for one statement. Which is also reflected on the same docs:

> but this custom error handler can (and should) call `error_reporting()` which will return 0 when the call that triggered the error was preceded by an `@`.

So, assuming you could have something like this very simple implementation, you would need to fine tune the details:

```php
function exceptional_error_handler($severity, $message, $file, $line)
{

    if (error_reporting() === 0) {
       // assuming your application always runs with `error_handling !== 0`,
       // e.g. by setting this during application bootstrap
       // that we got here means this is was a "silenced" error
       throw new \ErrorException("Silenced error! '$message'", 0, $severity, $file, $line); 
    }

    // regular (non-silenced) errors should respect your error_reporting levels
    if (!(error_reporting() & $severity)) {
        // This error code is not included in error_reporting
        return;
    }
    // everything else is converted to an exception
    throw new \ErrorException($message, 0, $severity, $file, $line);
}
set_error_handler("exceptional_error_handler");
```

This converts all errors to exceptions, simply noting with a different message when it was a "silenced" error, but your error handler could do logging or have any kind of custom logic.

By doing this, you could leave the existing/third party code untouched, and just add the error handling logic to the bootstrapping part of your application.

[Docs for set_error_handler().](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)